# Completely replacing a request in a WebExtension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm looking to make a web extension for Firefox that stores HTML pages and other resources in local storage and serves them for offline viewing. To do that, I need to intercept requests that the browser makes for the pages and the content in them.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried several approaches:

- The webRequest API doesn't allow fulfilling a request entirely - it can only block or redirect a request, or edit the response after it's been done.
- Service Workers can listen to the `fetch` event, which can do what I want, but calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register` in an addon page (the `moz-extension://<id>` domain) results in an error: `DOMException: The operation is insecure.` [Relevant Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1344561)
- I could possibly set up the service worker on a self hosted domain with a content script, but then it won't be completely offline.

Is there an API that I missed that can intercept requests from inside a web extension?